# How can I using Hadoop job to check the integrity of a large gzip file(.gz)?

Tags: java, validation, hadoop, gzip, integrity

I receive many gzip files(*.gz) from others everyday, and before putting them to HDFS and analyzing them, I need to check the integrity of all files(corrupt files will be deleted), if I use **gzip -t file_name** to check on local machine, it works, but the whole process is too slow because the file amount is very large, and most files are large enough to make the local validation a time consuming job.

So I turned to use a Hadoop job to do the parallel validation, each file will be validate in a mapper, and the corrupt file path will be output to a file, here are my codes:

**in Hadoop job setup:**

```
Job job = new Job(getConf());
job.setJarByClass(HdfsFileValidateJob.class);
job.setMapperClass(HdfsFileValidateMapper.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
job.setInputFormatClass(JustBytesInputFormat.class);
```

**in mapper:**

```
public class HdfsFileValidateMapper extends Mapper<JustBytesWritable, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HdfsFileValidateJob.class);

  private ByteArrayOutputStream bos;

  @Override
  protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    /* specify a split size(=HDFS block size here) for the ByteArrayOutputStream, which prevents frequently allocating
     * memory for it when writing data in [map] method */
    InputSplit inputSplit = context.getInputSplit();
    bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) ((FileSplit) inputSplit).getLength());
  }

  @Override
  protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    InputSplit inputSplit = context.getInputSplit();
    String filePath = ((FileSplit) inputSplit).getPath().toUri().getPath();   // e.g. "/user/hadoop/abc.txt"

    bos.flush();
    byte[] mergedArray = bos.toByteArray();   // the byte array which stores the data of the whole file
    if (!testUnGZip(mergedArray)) {   // broken file
      context.write(new Text(filePath), NullWritable.get());
    }
    bos.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void map(JustBytesWritable key, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    bos.write(key.getBytes());
  }

  /**
   * Test whether we can un-gzip a piece of data.
   *
   * @param data The data to be un-gzipped.
   * @return true for successfully un-gzipped the data, false otherwise.
   */
  private static boolean testUnGZip(byte[] data) {
    int numBytes2Read = 0;
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
    GZIPInputStream gzip = null;
    try {
      bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
      gzip = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int num;
      while ((num = gzip.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
        numBytes2Read += num;
        if (numBytes2Read % (1024 * 1024) == 0) {
          LOG.info(String.format("Number of bytes read: %d", numBytes2Read));
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    } finally {
      if (gzip != null) {
        try {
          gzip.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          LOG.error("Error while closing GZIPInputStream");
        }
      }
      if (bis != null) {
        try {
          bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          LOG.error("Error while closing ByteArrayInputStream");
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

In which I use two classes named JustBytesInputFormat and JustBytesWritable, can be found here: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12570327/justbytes.jar

Normally, this solution works fine, but when the single gzip file is large enough(e.g. 1.5G), the Hadoop job will fail due to a Java Heap Space problem, and the reason is obvious: for each file I first collect all the data into a memory buffer, and do the one-time validation at last, so the file size can’t be too large.

So I modified part of my code to:

```
  private boolean testUnGzipFail = false;

  @Override
  protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    InputSplit inputSplit = context.getInputSplit();
    String filePath = ((FileSplit) inputSplit).getPath().toUri().getPath();   // e.g. "/user/hadoop/abc.txt"

    if (testUnGzipFail) {   // broken file
      context.write(new Text(filePath), NullWritable.get());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void map(JustBytesWritable key, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (!testUnGZip(key.getBytes())) {
      testUnGzipFail = true;
    }
  }
```

This version fix the Hadoop job fail problem but **it doesn’t works right at all** ! In my E2E test, a totally fine gzip file(size: 1.5G) will be treated as a corrupt file !

So here is my problem: 
how can I do the validation correctly, and avoid the problem of reading all content of a single file into memory?

Any idea will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution would be to simply invoke `gzip -t` in parallel; `gzip` is probably faster than Java and when the files are big, the additional overhead of creating the process should become negligible.

Your solution is very slow. First of all, you load many, many gigabytes of data into RAM when you just need a few KB per file. Instead of `JustBytesInputFormat`, you should stream the data. Try to find a way to pass an `InputStream` to `testUnGZip()` instead of the whole file content.

If the file exists as a real file on the hard disk, try to use the NIO API to read from it; that would allow to memory map the file which makes reading even faster.

Comment: Invoke gzip -t in parallel seems a good way, but it needs a local file path, and in Hadoop job, the file in mapper you read may not be in local fs, but may be read from remote machine, so it's not feasible.

Comment: There must be an API in Hadoop which gives you an `InputStream` (or another way to read the file in chunks). Use that. Also, if the file is on a remote machine, you absolutely have to run the job on the same CPU - copying the file over the network is extremely costly.

Comment: I also would suggest you move the "check" step before you upload the corrupt data to Hadoop. Hadoop makes it easy to distribute the jobs on a cluster but it doesn't make it cheaper - in fact, Hadoop is much slower than processing the data locally. But since it can run many jobs at the same time, you can balance the two goals. If you can, then check the files while they are uploaded so you don't even waste disk space for corrupt files.

Comment: Checking the file is many times faster than the upload, so the check isn't the bottleneck anymore.

Comment: I'm uploading the files using GNU Parallel, so it's not slow to put them to HDFS. Instead, the local gzip -t validation is really slow. In my environment, the way of using GUN Parallel to put files + using Hadoop job to validate has save at least 5 hours per day. We just because couldn't tolerate the inefficiency of local jobs so we turned to the Hadoop way.

Comment: At the very beginning, I was just did the same as you said, which is: local validation, delete corrupt files before putting them to HDFS, and no Hadoop job. But this way is really too time-consuming, so I had no choice but to change it to current status.

Comment: Good. How about the streaming API of Hadoop. Did you check that?